# Choosing random items in a while loop does not behave as expected

Tags: python

I would like to choose exactly n items from the Lists (P1,P2,P3).
If they are not already in the result list (LIST) they should be appended/extended. If the while loop reaches n (here <=3) it should stop. 
But I get results with 4,6 items. Why ?
Thank you.

```
from random import choice

P1 = ["a", "b","c", "d", "e","f","g","h","i","j"]
P2 = ["a","m","b","n","e","z","h","g","f","j"]
P3 = [("a","b"), ("c","e"), ("g","a"), ("m","j"), ("d","f")]

LIST = []

while len(LIST) <=3:
    c1, c2 = choice(P3)
    d = choice(P1)
    e = choice(P2)
    f = choice(P1)
    g = choice(P2)
    if c1 not in LIST and c2 not in LIST:
        LIST.extend([c1,c2])
        if d not in LIST:
            LIST.append(d)
        if e not in LIST:
            LIST.append(e) 
        if f not in LIST:
            LIST.append(f) 
        if g not in LIST:
            LIST.append(g) 
print LIST
```

Comment: The length constraint is checked only between the iterations. If you add any number of items inside the `while` clause, nothing will prevent it (though the loop will stop after that).

Comment: One more thing: Even if you only appended a single element per iteration, you would still end up with 4 elements in `LIST`. As long as `len(LIST)` is smaller or _equal_ to 3, it will append more elements. So you will always get at least 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` executes the whole loop, and before starting the next iteration, it checks whether the condition is still true.

Inside of a single iteration of your loop, you extend the list by up to 6 elements.

If you really only want 3 elements, that you would have to check the condition every time you appended something, like so:

```
    while True: 
        c1,c2 = choice(P3)
        d = choice(P1)
        e = choice(P2)
        f = choice(P1)
        g = choice(P2)
        if c1 not in LIST and c2 not in LIST:
            LIST.append(c1)
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
            LIST.append(c2)
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
        if d not in LIST:
            LIST.append(d)
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
        if e not in LIST:
            LIST.append(e) 
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
        if f not in LIST:
            LIST.append(f) 
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
        if g not in LIST:
            LIST.append(g) 
            if len(LIST) >= 3:
                break
```

Comment: This works fine. If there would be a simpler option it would be cool. Thanks a lot for solving the problem !

Answer (score 0):

That is because you check that condition at start of each loop.

At start of the loop condition will be 0, 1, 2 but in the loop you can insert up to 5 new elements, increasing it possibly up to 7.

Comment: Check condition after each if and break from loop if it is not fulfilled. Another option is to trim the list at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

You check if there are less/equal than 3 Elements in you list

```
    while len(LIST) <=3:
```

after that, you add up to 5 items before you check again.

so if your last loop got 3 items at its begining and it adds up to 5 items, your list can contain up to 8 Elements.